# Is it possible to create custom follow-up flags for tasks in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

This question is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/17786/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-follow-up-flags-in-outlook-2007) question but the solution in that question is used for mails. Could someone provide a solution for tasks, please? Thanks!

Comment: You should see "Custom" in Follow Up list.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it will be much more convenient to set a 2-week/1-month follow-up instead of using custom every time.

Comment: I'm afraid this is by design and you can submit your feedback via https://outlook.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround.
You have to create one task and set the custom follow up as last date of current month. This will create a category of This month in your task list.

create another task and set the custom follow up as last date of next month. This will create a category of Next month in your task list.

create another task and set the custom follow up as last date of 2 months later. This will create a category of Later in your task list.

Now, all you have to do is to drag your tasks in these categories up and down. This is how I do it. Every month, it may require some redragging of tasks to right categories but it helps to keep the tasks organized.